# SQL - find data from master table that link to another table

Tags: c#, sql

I have 3 table, PatientDoctor (link Patient Table Primary Key and  Doctor Table Primary Key), Patient and Doctor

---

In my Doctor Table,

```
----------------------------------
|ID|Doctor Name|Specialty|Year Ex|
----------------------------------
|1 |Alex       |Transplt | 3     |
----------------------------------
```

In my patient Doctor,

> ```
> -------------------------------
> |ID|Patient Name|Ward|Diseases|
> -------------------------------
> |5 |Berns       |1234| Cancer |
> -------------------------------
> ```

In my PatientDoctor,

> ```
> ------------------------
> |ID|Patient ID|DoctorID|
> ------------------------
> |6 |5         |1       |
> ------------------------
> ```

Now, I would like to search doctor associated to the patient, like if i search "Alex" from ComboBox, the listBox will show all the patient associated. This is the code i work on so far, but still return an error.

```
> if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex==-1)
>                 MessageBox.Show("Nothing to search!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
>             else
>             {
>                 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
>                 {
>                     //string sql = "SELECT * FROM Patient " + "WHERE [Patient Name] = @name";
>                     string sql = "SELECT a.[Patient Name] FROM Patient a " + "INNER JOIN PatientDoctor b ON a.ID = b.[DoctorID] " + "INNER
> JOIN Doctor c ON b.ID = c.[Doctor Name]" + "WHERE c.[Doctor Name] =
> @DID";
>                     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
>                     {
>                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DID", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
> 
>                         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>                         SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>                         ad.Fill(dt);
> 
>                         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
>                         { //check if the query returns any data
>                             listBox1.DataSource = dt;
>                             //dg1.DataBind();
>                         }
>                         else
>                         {
>                             MessageBox.Show("Record not found!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
>                         }
>                         textBox1.Text = "";
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
```

Comment: "it still return an error" You do realize that we are not sitting right at your computer? We can't see what error it is you have? You need to explicitly state your issue.

Comment: This is not about your error, but should be mentioned: Try to put your bussiness code and data access code to other layer in your application. I mean: Create classes (Services, Repositories) that expose methods and follow SOLID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid. Do not put sql code into the forms code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space here `c.[Doctor Name]" + "WHERE c.[Doctor Name] =` ... it should rather be `c.[Doctor Name]" + " WHERE c.[Doctor Name] =`

Your query should look like

```
string sql = "SELECT a.[Patient Name] FROM Patient a INNER JOIN PatientDoctor b ON a.ID = b.[DoctorID] INNER JOIN Doctor c ON b.ID = c.[Doctor Name] WHERE c.[Doctor Name] = @DID";
```

Comment: That won't make a difference because of the identifier is delimited.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong.  You are joining a name to an `id`.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT p.[Patient Name]
FROM Patient p INNER JOIN 
     PatientDoctor pd
     ON p.ID = pd.PatientID INNER JOIN
     Doctor d
     ON pd.DoctorId = d.Id
WHERE pd.DoctorName = @DID;
```

Notes:

- Rename `@DID` to something like `@DoctorName`.  You want to search by the name not the id.
- The join for the patient name uses `DoctorId`, which is nonsensical.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table name, so the query is easier to follow.
- Don't depend on `AddWithValue()`.  Add the parameters with the explicitly correct type.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Doctor Name'.'

Comment: @KoayHv . . . Adjust the column names to be whatever they really are in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following from c# :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication55
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable doctors = new DataTable();
            doctors.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            doctors.Columns.Add("Doctor Name", typeof(string));
            doctors.Columns.Add("Speciality", typeof(string));
            doctors.Columns.Add("Year Ex", typeof(int));

            doctors.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Alex", "Transplt", 3});

            DataTable patients = new DataTable();
            patients.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            patients.Columns.Add("Patient Name", typeof(string));
            patients.Columns.Add("Ward", typeof(int));
            patients.Columns.Add("Diseases", typeof(string));

            patients.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Berns", 1234, "Cancer"});

            DataTable patientDoctor = new DataTable();
            patientDoctor.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            patientDoctor.Columns.Add("Patient ID", typeof(int));
            patientDoctor.Columns.Add("DoctorID", typeof(int));

            patientDoctor.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6,5,1});

            string doctorName = "Alex";
            int doctID = doctors.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Doctor Name") == doctorName).Select(x => x.Field<int>("ID")).FirstOrDefault();

            var results = (from patDr in patientDoctor.AsEnumerable()
                           join pat in patients.AsEnumerable() on patDr.Field<int>("Patient ID") equals pat.Field<int>("ID")
                           select new { doctorID = patDr.Field<int>("DoctorID"), patient = pat.Field<string>("Patient Name") })
                           .Where(x => x.doctorID == doctID).Select(x => x.patient).ToList();

        }


    }

}
```